# How to fix "This expression has a type of 'void'..." error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I'm building a Pomodoro app in Flutter using MobX and encountering the error:

> This expression has a type of `void` so its value can't be used.

Here's the relevant code and error screenshot:

**Code:**

```
class Pomodoro extends StatelessWidget {
  const Pomodoro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final store = Provider.of<PomodoroStore>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Cronometro(),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
          child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            EntradaTempo(
                titulo: 'Work',
                valor: store.tempoWork,
                inc: store.incrementarTempoWork(),
                dec: store.reduceTempoRest(),
            ),
            EntradaTempo(
                titulo: 'Relax',
                valor: store.tempoRest,
                inc: store.incrementarTempoRest(),
                dec: store.reduceTempoRest(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

**As you can see in the image, I encountered errors in these lines:**

```
EntradaTempo(
  titulo: 'Work',
  valor: store.tempoWork,
  inc: store.incrementarTempoWork(),
  dec: store.reduceTempoRest(),
),
EntradaTempo(
  titulo: 'Relax',
  valor: store.tempoRest,
  inc: store.incrementarTempoRest(),
  dec: store.reduceTempoRest(),
),
```

**Specific Question:** How can I resolve this `void` type error in my Flutter code within the context of my Pomodoro app?

**Context:** I'm following a tutorial, but the provided solution may not be directly applicable to my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of `EntradaTempo` for `inc` and `dec` are probably some sort of `Function`, maybe a `VoidCallback`. The issue here is that you are not passing the function to the parameter, but you are calling the function and passing its return type, which might be `void`.

You will probably want to remove the parentheses `()` at the end to avoid calling the function instead of simply passing it.

```
EntradaTempo(
  titulo: 'Relax',
  valor: store.tempoRest,
  inc: store.incrementarTempoRest, // without '()'
  dec: store.reduceTempoRest, // without '()'
),
```

An other way would be to create a new inline function there that calls it.

```
EntradaTempo(
  titulo: 'Relax',
  valor: store.tempoRest,
  inc: () => store.incrementarTempoRest(),
  dec: () => store.reduceTempoRest(), // inline function, calling the passed function
),
```

Answer (score 1):

call your function without the parenthesis `()`:

```dart
EntradaTempo(
  titulo: 'title',
  valor: store.tempoRest,
  inc: store.incrementarTempoRest,
  dec: store.reduceTempoRest,
),
```